# How to create search data in Angular?

Tags: angular, input

I tried to create search input but something went wrong! Here is HTML:

```html
<div>
  <input type="search" id="searchTerm" name = "searchTerm" placeholder="Search Food Mine!" (ngSubmit)="search()">
  <button (click)="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Here is Angular component

```
  searchTerm:string;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  search():void{
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/search/'+ this.searchTerm);
  }
```

it's seem like fail in data between HTML and Angular component. I'm trying to get data of input text to `search()` in component. But seem like it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your template to:

```
<div>
  <input type="search" id="searchTerm" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" placeholder="Search Food Mine!">
  <button (click)="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Don't forget to import FormsModule in your module (AppModule probably) like this:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    FormsModule
  ]
}
...
```

Comment: thanks for reply me but it not working. I have a diffrent way to fix that below

Answer (score 1):

i tried this way and it work!

```
HTML
<input type="search" name="search-box"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" class=" w-60" (keyup)="searching($event)">
```

And component

```
searching(event:any){
    console.log("routing");
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/search/' + event.target.value );
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).